# Disable WebSocket in create-react-app

Tags: reactjs, websocket, create-react-app

I'm just starting with create-react-app, and I found it annoying to see WebSocket errors in console (and the Chrome loading indicator shows up longer). Probably I will need WebSocket someday, but right now I just want to disable it. How do I do that?

Answer (score 1):

Websockets are used for hot reloading in development mode.

More info about disabling hot reloading here: https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/1940